# Disable Multi-window for only one activity

Tags: android, multi-window

I am trying to build an app with multi-window support, but there is an activity for which i want to disable multi-window support. I am targeting android version 26. So multi window is enabled by default. To disable multi-window support for a particular activity, i am using

```
 android:resizeableActivity="false"
```

in the manifest for this activity. This doesn't work, I am still able to use the activity in multi-window.

According to the developr guide [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#resizeableActivity),

> If this value is false, and the user attempts to launch the activity in multi-window mode, the activity takes over the full screen.

Which does not happen in my case. I am unable to understand what I am doing wrong. I also tried using

```
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

along with the resizableActivity property, but it doesn't help.
Is it even possible to disable multi-window for a single activity in the app?

Answer (score 0):

While starting a New Activity You should add `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag to Intent.Otherwise it will inherit the properties from the root activity.